# Как изменить стили :before непосредственно в атрибуте style=""?

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, допустим есть ссылка:

```css
a {
  color: black;
}

a:before {
  content: '!';
}
```

```html
<a href="url">text</a>
```

И таких ссылок несколько. Есть задача сделать `color` текста в `:before` разноцветным (у каждой ссылки свой) до  вывода (в php).

Как можно это сделать? Я думал о чем-то на подобии  `<a href="url" style="this::before{color: red;}">text</a>` но это не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Невозможно передать стиль для псевдоэлемента в атрибуте `style`. Это связано с тем, что в `style` указываются стили к текущему элементу, а `a:before`, это псевдоэлемент, и он не соответствует элементу `a`.

В качестве альтернативы рекомендую создать классы для каждого стиля, и каждой ссылке присвоить свой класс. А у классов уже реализовывать стили для псевдоэлемента `:before`